# JPA Query Many To One nullable relationship

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following entities and would like to seek help on how to query for selected attributes from both side of the relationship. Here is my model. Assume all tables are properly created in the db. JPA provider I am using is Hibernate.

```
@Entity
public class Book{

@Id
private long id; 
@Column(nullable = false)
private String ISBNCode;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Person<Author> author;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
private Person<Borrower> borrower;

}

@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "personType")
public abstract class Person<T>{

@Id
private long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Info information;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(PersonType.Author)

public class Author extends Person<Author> {

private long copiesSold;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(PersonType.Borrower)

public class Borrower extends Person<Borrower> {

.....
}

@Entity

public class Info {

@Id
private long id;
@Column(nullable=false)
private String firstName;
@Column(nullable=false)
private String lastName;
......;

}
```

As you can see, the book table has a many to one relation to Person that is not nullable and Person that is nullable.

I have a requirement to show, the following in a tabular format -

```
ISBNCode - First Name - Last Name - Person Type
```

How can I write a JPA query that will allow me to select only attributes that I would want. I would want to get the attributes ISBN Code from Book, and then first and last names from the Info object that is related to Person Object that in turn is related to the Book object. I would not want to get all information from Info object, interested only selected information e.g first and last name in this case.

Please note that the relation between the Borrower and Book is marked with optional=true, meaning there may be a book that may not have been yet borrowed by someone (obviously it has an author).

Answer (score 0):

Example to search for books by the author "Marc":

Criteria JPA Standard

```
CriteriaQuery<Book> criteria = builder.createQuery( Book.class );  
Root<Book> personRoot = criteria.from( Book.class );  
Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
List<Expression<Boolean>> expressions = predicate.getExpressions();  
Path<Object> firtsName = personRoot.get("author").get("information").get("firstName");
expressions.add(builder.equal(firtsName, "Marc"));
criteria.where( predicate );  
criteria.select(personRoot); 
List<Book> books = em.createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();
```

Criteria JPA Hibernate

```
List<Book> books = (List<Book>)sess.createCriteria(Book.class).add( Restrictions.eq("author.information.firstName", "Marc") ).list();
```

We recommend using hibernate criterias for convenience and possibilities.

Regards,